# C++11 simplify syntax of a template function calling different specializations of the same template function

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

There are a couple of template functions (with identical signatures) like:

```
template <typename T, typename P> void f1(T t, P p);
template <typename T, typename P> void f2(T t, P p);
```

There are also a couple of functions with identical logic that call them with different predicates:

```
template <typename T> void g1(T t)
{
    f1(t, Pred1{});
    ...
    f1(t, Pred2{});
    ...
}

// same as g1 but calls f2 instead of f1
template <typename T> void g2(T t)
{
    f2(t, Pred3{});
    ...
    f2(t, Pred4{});
    ...
}
```

I've tried to generalize them and all I could come up with is something like:

```
template <typename P1, typename P2, typename FP1, typename FP2, typename T>
void g(T t, FP1 fp1, FP2 fp2, P1 p1, P2 p2)
{
    fp1(t, p1);
    ...
    fp2(t, p2);
    ...
}

template <typename T> void g1(T t)
{
    g(t, f1<T, P1>, f2<T, P2>, P1{}, P2{});
}
```

So it is excessively verbose, especially with real types, not toy ones as in this example.
I have to pass separately each `f()` specialization that is called in a generalized function `g()`, and I have to mention each predicate twice (first, its type in f specialization, second, predicate object as a separate parameter).

If I remove `P1 p1, P2 p2` arguments from `g()`, I still have to call it like: `g<P1, P2>(t, f1<T, P1>, f1<T, P2>)`

Is there a way to make it simpler and avoid repetitions?

I'm limited to C++11/14.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have template template function parameter.

Way to pass overload is to wrap them in Functor.

So your generic `g` becomes:

```
template <typename F, typename T>
void g(F f, T t)
{
    f(t, Pred1{});
    ...
    f(t, Pred2{});
    ...
}
```

Creation of functor is easier in C++14 with generic lambda:

```
g([](auto e, auto pred){ return f1(e, pred); }, t);
```

In C++11, functor is more verbose (especially with capture):

```
struct F1
{
    template <typename T, typename Pred>
    auto operator()(T t, Pred pred) const {
        return f1(t, pred);
    }
};

g(F1{}, t);
```

Comment: Thanks, generic lambda was exactly what I needed. I feel dumb for not figuring out how to apply it.

Answer (score 1):

If you can turn your function templates into functor templates (callable structs), then you will have some freedom to play with template template arguments.

For example:

```
template <template <typename...> typename Func, typename T, typename P, typename ...Ps>
struct Caller
{
    void operator()(T t, P p, Ps ...ps)
    {
        Func<T, P>{}(t, p);
        Caller<Func, T, Ps...>{}(t, ps...);
    }
};

template <template <typename...> typename Func, typename T, typename P>
struct Caller<Func, T, P>
{
    void operator()(T t, P p)
    {
        Func<T, P>{}(t, p);
    }
};

template <template <typename...> typename Func, typename T, typename ...Ps>
void Call(T t, Ps ...ps)
{
    Caller<Func, T, Ps...>{}(t, ps...);
}

template <typename T, typename P> struct f1 {
    void operator()(T t, P p) { std::cout << "f1 " << t << ", " << p << "\n"; }
};

template <typename T, typename P> struct f2 {
    void operator()(T t, P p) { std::cout << "f2 " << t << ", " << p << "\n"; }
};

int main() {
    Call<f1>(1.0001, 2, 3.05f, 'x');
    Call<f2>(2, 3, "bar!");
}
```

Prints

```
f1 1.0001, 2
f1 1.0001, 3.05
f1 1.0001, x
f2 2, 3
f2 2, bar!
```

Unfortunately function templates cannot be passed as template arguments.

Comment: Thanks, this solution extends even to an arbitrary number of predicates. Still I opted for a simpler generic lambda.